# Solr suggester: Context Filter incorrectly applied to FileDictionaryFactory

Tags: solr

In the [docs](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/suggester.html#context-filtering), it says that context filtering only comes into effect "when using `AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory` or `BlendedInfixLookupFactory`, when backed by a `DocumentDictionaryFactory`".

However, I have found that the context filtering is applied when a `FileDictionaryFactory` is used. This doesn't work, as there are no documents for the context filter to be applied to.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/suggest?qt=suggest&suggest.dictionary=location&q=russia
> Returns ["Russia"]

http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/suggest?qt=suggest&suggest.dictionary=location&q=russia&cfq=a
> Returns []
```

This is my suggester config:

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">location</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">FileDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="sourceLocation">tdwg.txt</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
    <str name="highlight">false</str>
  </lst>

  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">common-name</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">region.vernacular_names_t</str>
    <str name="indexPath">common_name_suggest</str>
    <str name="contextField">searchable.context_ss</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
    <str name="highlight">false</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

As you can see, for one of the suggesters I *do* want context filtering (and it is working correctly). So I can't simply remove the `suggest.cfq` parameter from my request.

Is there anything I can change about my configuration so that the context filter is not applied to my `FileDictionaryFactory` suggester?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already faced this issue in the past, it appears that when `suggest.cfq` is present in the request, context filtering will be applied for *every* (enabled) lookup implementations that supports it (AnalyzingInfix and BlendedInfix).

It seems there is no other solution than switching to another lookup impl. than these 2 for the dictionary which you don't want to apply context filtering.

For example you can try to use the `FuzzyLookupFactory` for the "location" suggester and the context filter won't be applied.

---

**NB:** this is a workaround, as it's not possible to get *infix* matches with FuzzyLookup or AnalyzingLookup implementations (only the whole prefix from the input token(s) is taken into account).

If you really need infix matches for both suggesters, it's likely you will have to  make 2 parallel requests before merging the suggestions :/.

Comment: I suspected this was the case... do you know if `FuzzyLookup` supports infix matching?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it will only match the whole prefix from the input token(s).